# How to run PHP 5.5.4 mcrypt run on CentOS 6.4?

Tags: centos, php, mcrypt

I am getting the following error:

> PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/mcrypt.so' -
>   /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by
>   /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/mcrypt.so)

**Does mcrypt require glibc 2.14?**

We are running CentOS 6.4 (latest stable version of CentOS) and it comes with glibc 2.12 (can't really upgrade glibc as being a core part of OS, changing it will likely break lots of stuff)

**How do I make my PHP 5.5.4 run mcsypt under these circumstances?**

Current configuration (phpinfo output) is [here](http://www.filedropper.com/php-config).

Comment: What does your PHP Configuration look like? IE, the ./configure command. You can find this by doing a simple `phpinfo()` OR `php -i | head`

Comment: Will post phpinfo output above.

Answer (score 3):

I was also having issues installing mcrypt on my VPS dev server so I thought I would post my solution in the hopes that it helps someone. I am running Centos OS 6.5 and had upgraded PHP to 5.5.13 using the Webtatic EL yum repository. https://webtatic.com/packages/php55/

First shh into your server

```
ssh admin@domain.com
```

initially I was trying to do (which was not working):

```
yum update
yum install php-mcrypt
```

I then realized my mistake when I looked at php -v and realized php-common was conflicting as the above code was trying to load a dependency from 5.3.

I then executed the following correct commands:

```
rpm -Uvh http://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm
yum update
yum install php55w-mcrypt
service httpd restart
```

This worked perfectly for me.

I also read while researching this issue that some people did have to add the extension to their .ini file manually by adding the following line but i did not have to do this.

```
extension=mcrypt.so
```

you can find the location of your php.ini file by looking at phpinfo(); and see which configuration it is loading. For me the following ini files were loading:

```
/etc/php.ini
/etc/php.d/mcrypt.ini
/var/www/vhosts/system/domain.com/etc/php.ini
```

If the installation is successful then you will see the extension when you echo phpinfo();

[image: mcrypt in php info]

Comment: Just wanted to add an update to this... the above solution got my app to run in browser just fine but when I tried to run php artisan migrate from the CLI I got the mcrypt required error again. To solve I uncommented extension=mcrypt.so in /etc/php.d/mcrypt.ini and then it worked fine on the CLI also

Answer (score 2):

Try installing php-mcrypt using yum. That should pull in any other libraries you need to run it.

```
yum install php-mcrypt
```

Comment: What PHP packages are installed?

    rpm -qa php*

Answer (score 0):

In light of your update, it would appear that you are trying to use the MCrypt extension built from another PHP Source which was created by an updated GLIBC library. The only proper solution I can see is the following:

You first need to ensure you have libmcrypt, libmcrypt-devel, and mcrypt installed before continuing. Check your CentOS repository.

1. Download the PHP Source from http://php.net
2. Untar the downloaded source `tar -zxf php-5.5.4.tar.gz`
3. cd into the source `cd php-5.4.4`
4. Copy your current `./configure` string. The whole thing!
5. Add support for Mcrypt `--with-mcrypt=/usr` and run the new configure command
6. make && make install
7. restart Apache and PHP-FPM

This will keep your current configuration just as CentOS has built it but with the additional support of MCrypt as you are looking to have. Once you've done this, you **do not** need to enable the MCrypt extension in your php.ini file as it will be built into PHP itself and will be automatically loaded for you now.

When in doubt, you can also read up on the installation here https://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.installation.php

Comment: Thanks! Since I currently have PHP 5.5.4, I suspect you mean that first I should grab CentOS supplies PHP (5.3.3) and replace the currently installed newer version with it. Then I should enable mcrypt, and finally upgrade back to PHP 5.5.4 following the steps you laid out. Did I get that right?

Comment: No don't downgrade. Since CentOS doesn't build PHP with the support you are looking to have, you'll need to manually build it yourself using the steps I've outlined above. Since you already have 5.4.x installed, following the steps outlined it will simply overwrite what you've already installed with only one minor change. Since you know what the `./configure` line looks like, this makes it very simple for you.